# Error while running "react-native run-android"

Tags: react-native

Please help me with this error below. And sorry for the bad formating of the error. I dont know how exactly i should display the errors here.

internal/fs/utils.js:220
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/external/xsel'

```
at Object.chmodSync (fs.js:1104:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/copyToClipBoard.js:50:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/middleware/copyToClipBoardMiddleware.js:8:47)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30) {
```

errno: -1,
  syscall: 'chmod',

code: 'EPERM',

path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/external/xsel'
}

Answer (score 1):

use this command for getting permission in Linux. replace userName with your Linux username

```
sudo chown userName -R /dev/kvm
```

for me

```
sudo chown aurangzaib -R /dev/kvm
```

Comment: Okay, its solved. All I did is changed the permission to my userName for react-native. Thanx, It gave me a hint.

Comment: cmd shows no such file or directory. I'm running this command in the root of my react project , is it right?